# Where to perform state changes with Clean Architecture in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, state-management, clean-architecture

### When using Clean Architecture with flutter we see a diagram similar to this:

[image]

(I wrote MobX package as an example, but it could be anything like BLoC, Redux...)

I may have a problem with this diagram since the Store resides in presentation layer and ***is responsible for changing the state***.

Imagine that the app loads a list of todos through a method called "getTodos" implementend in TodosStore.
The "getTodos" implementation might be:

```
 _state = State.loading();
 final result = GetTodos();
 _state = State.done();
```

(I oversimplified things)

It starts by updating the state to loading, calls a use case returning the list and set state to done.

The problems I found here:

1. **Stores are responsible** for calling UC, updating state, handling errors...
2. **Use case is simply a bridge and does not handle the business logic**

This is a rather simple example.
But let's imagine that I have a view with 3 lists of differents data (it may be an absurd example).
The view interacts with 3 differents stores. There's a button in an app bar. Its goal is to clear the 3 lists.

How to achieve that behavior ?

- The button onPressed method will need to call "clearData" for each store
- The "clear" method of each store will simply updates its properties

The thing is that the view is not as dumb as we wanted.
The store **is not even interacting with any use case**

**Should a ClearLists use case be legitimate here?**

### Since I do not like having much logic in presentation layer, I tend to follow this diagram:

[image]

Each view has its own ViewModel. The VM simply interacts with the Use Case. These UC may or may not return a value. For instance: my UC is a ValidateNumberRange, I might not interact with a store. It makes sense to return a bool. But if my UC is a ClearTodoList, it might interact with a store. The success or failure may be a stored value. That way returning a value may not be useful.

With this new diagram, the "GetTodos" use case callable method implementation might be:

```
store.set(State.loading());
final result = repo.getTodos();
result.fold(
   (failureMsg) { store.set(State.failure(failureMsg)); },
   (newList) { store.set(State.done(newList)); },
);
```

- Use case handles the state management logic
- The View calls a VM method. The VM calls a UC and observe changes in Store (through MobX here)

### I ask myself a ton of questions:

- Did I correctly understand the role of UC in clean architecture ?
- **Is changing state (to loading, done, failure) considered business logic ?**
- Where would you put state management solution in your app ?

I look forward to hear your thoughts

Comment: Maybe `Store` class could be placed in `data` layer, so it will be easily modified by different `UseCases` / `(Flux) Dispatchers` from domain layer. Store would be only responsible for storing state and only offer get/set methods. That should be inlined to what `data` layer actually do. Also `Presentation` could access directly `Store` without a `domain` proxy (however You can use it) as it would just listen to the changes, preserving unidirectional dataflow.
`Domain` layer will contain base models for Your `Store` and `Loading`, but I will just use it without storing it.

Comment: Hi bro, I'm asking ton of question, just like you almost 3 years ago. Did you have answer for this?

Comment: Hi guys. I've also recently interested in problem like this not as a Flutter dev, but frontend dev. But my issue is almost the same. I do not want to store my state into something platform specific library and I have some complex state, so it's an essential part. My current thoughts: I created an interface of store that I expect to use inside usecases. Since I'm writing some statefull app, then state is an important and complex part of the app, so it's acceptable to write usecases that not only communicate with some repository but also save something into a store.

Answer (score 3):

> Use cases encapsulate business rules, and they are platform-agnostic and delivery-mechanism-agnostic (e.g. UI).
> Use Cases are based on functionality, but without implementation details.
> Book:
> https://dannorth.net/introducing-bdd

changing state is responsibility of presentation layer; Presentation Layer != UI Layer

Think as like this:

```
Domain Layer <= infrastructure layer <= application layer <= presentation layer <= UI Layer
```

the dependencies always should be inward.
imagine like this: Side effects free business logic (functional core) is always in center and the rest (stateful elements, UI, frameworks) surround it.

from your diagram:
AppState and ViewModel always reside in presentation layer. Flutter specific classes are belongs to the UI.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Hashem. What if the state is not platform specific ? I mean, I have my own state solution that are not flutter specific. I was not entirely satisfied with the existing state management solution that are too dependent on the platform. In my case, the platform specific code (presentation layer) only registers to stores and observes changes by providing a callback. This code can now be used inside a web project. From what I understand in your comment it does not respect the clean arch am I right ?

Comment: Presentation layer is platform agnostic. so you can reuse it. there is no template called clean architecture. clean architecture is a concept that encourages you decouple low level details (frameworks) from high level details (application logic) by using abstractions. so you can replace components easily as long they conform to boundary interfaces. think like this: you should be able easiy change your UI layer and be able to reuse you code for windows, Mac, linux, web, mobile